# jQuery Repeat Loop of Array To Change Tag Attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slider

I am making a simple slider that works by changing the `src` attribute of an `img` tag and the attributes of anchor tags. This is what I have come up with so far:

```
(function($){
    var slides = [
        'http://placehold.it/801x350',
        'http://placehold.it/802x350',
        'http://placehold.it/803x350'
    ],
    titles = [
        'Title 1',
        'Title 2',
        'Title 3'
    ],
    links =  [
        'http://test1.com',
        'http://test2.com',
        'http://test3.com'
    ],
    image = $('#stretch-img'),
    anchor = $('.featured-title>h2>a');

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        image.attr('src', slides[0]);
        anchor.attr('href', links[0]);
        anchor.html(titles[0]);
    }, 3000);
})(jQuery);
```

I want the interval to loop through the arrays continuously with a simple fade effect. What can be the best way to do this or any way to do this really, coz I've got none.

Thanks!

I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To loop through your array you can set a current-position-variable and a variable that saves the length of the array:

```
var current = 0,
    length  = slides.length,
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        image.attr('src', slides[current]);
        anchor.attr('href', links[current]).html(titles[current]);

        current++;
        if (current >= length) {
            current = 0;
        }
    }, 3000);
```

Then to fade you can fade-out, change the source, then fade-back-in:

```
        image.fadeOut(500, function () {
            image.attr('src', slides[current]).fadeIn(500);
            anchor.attr('href', links[current]).html(titles[current]);

            current++;
            if (current >= length) {
                current = 0;
            }
        });
```

This can lead to the image not quite being loaded when the `fadeIn(500)` kicks-in, which can be fixed by using an event handler attached to the `load` event for the `image` element:

```
var image = $('#stretch-img').on('load', function () {
    image.fadeIn(500);
});
```

Then you can remove the `fadeIn(500)` from the interval function since it will fire when the image has loaded. The `load` event will fire whenever the source of the image changes and the new source finishes loading.

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and is the same as `.bind()` in this case.

Comment: Amazing. That works perfectly. Thanks you so much. I really appreciate it.

One question though: I used the code with the fade in and out. There was a problem. The slides and titles were at a difference of one. i.e. for image 1 title was 2. I fixed it by placing the anchor modifying code in the fadoOut callback as well.

Why did I have to do that? the current++ was after both the statements. I would really like to understand this. Thanks again.

Comment: @Aayush That happened because the `current` variable was being incremented before the `fadeOut` callback function. I updated my answer to increment the `current` variable inside the `fadeOut` callback function.